# telnet to a switch from a java program in windows and get the output

Tags: java, cmd, telnet

From a Java program, I want to test if the switch with the specific IP address and port is available for telnet or not. So was planning to run telnet and exit. If it gives error as "Could not open connection" or "Connect failed", we can not access the switch. And if does not give any error, it is accessible for telnet.

I was executing below code,

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /C telnet "+IP+ " " +port );
//Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /C ver");
p.waitFor();
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
String line;
while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
System.out.println(line);
}
in.close();
```

But it does not give any output whether it is available or not. When I run the same telnet command on the command prompt, it works fine. But does not work from java.

The statement,

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /C ver");
```

works fine and gives back the version.

I don't know how should I telnet to the switch and exit and get back the error to see if it is available or not.

Thanks,
Peeyush

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling the telnet command, you could just use a Socket inside java and try to open a connection to the desired host and port.
This will work for most cases, if no special handling of control codes is required.

As an alternative: [Apache Commons Net](http://commons.apache.org/net/) contains a java telnet client library.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. But that will need server running on the host-port to accept the connection right ? We don't want to do it that way.

Am I understanding it correctly ?

Comment: You don't need to change anything on the server side. If the server (in your case the switch) accepts the connection you can use it, otherwise you will get some exception or notification about it.

Comment: Hey thanks, it was really easy this way. :)
In case of success it executes normally, else it gives IOException.